# Laravel 5.6: Displaying HTML Data with a blade

Tags: laravel, date, laravel-blade, laravel-5.6

I am trying to display it with Blade:

```
{{ date('d M Y'); }}
```

I got this error when I did not make a mistake in syntax

> Exception message: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';',
>   expecting ',' or ')'

when i echo with blade `<?php echo date('d M Y'); ?>` then i perfectly got output today's date

> 03 Apr 2018

How do I display HTML with Blade in Laravel 5.6?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `;` from your code, `{{}}` doesn't need additional `;`

```
{{ date('d M Y') }}
```